# Concurrent debugging / unit testing alternitive to MS CHESS

Tags: c#, unit-testing, concurrency

I was recently reading a question here  (some time this week), which I can't find again ><, where someone was asking about concurrent testing.

One of the suggestions was [CHESS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/default.aspx) however I can't use this due to the licence for the VS2008 Pro version being only for academic use, and I don't have Team System.

Does anyone know of an alternative I can use?

Comment: http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/394900/how-to-write-an-automated-test-for-thread-safety/394941#394941 might be the question you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Typemock Racer](http://learn.typemock.com/typemock-racer).

But it is not free. I am not sure whether they have academic license, though

Comment: Its not available any more :(

Answer (score 0):

Jinx should do it for ya.

http://www.corensic.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try ChessTool.codeplex.com, but again it is same under Academic license. But supports .Net 4.0